# Can't export issues's report on SonarQube Community EditionVersion 7.9.1

Tags: sonarqube

CentOS 7, SonarQube Community Edition Version 7.9.1 , Java 11

I want to export report of Sonar's issues to csv or excel format. But I can't find this kind of menu on SonarQube.

Is it possible on Community Edition Version 7.9.1 ?

Answer (score 0):

the community version does not support report exporting. You can use this https://github.com/cnescatlab/sonar-cnes-report
This also support command line version